# Canvas application not working in IE9 & working incorrectly in FF4b7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, html, canvas

I'm working on an online roguelike game. It's current version is located [here](http://dun.shell.tor.hu). It's working fine in Chrome 9 and Firefox 3.6, but it makes Firefox 4 beta 7 unresponsive for about a minute on every move and IE9 just says that it doesn't support `<canvas>` tag.

Could someone please explain these strange behaviours of IE9 and FF4b7?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The problems are both in beta browsers?

Comment: @Josiah: well, actually, yes. But I've seen lots of canvas applications working fine in IE9 and FF4, so I find it strange that mine doesn't work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In IE9 hit F12 and you'll see your site is loading in quirks mode which is why it doesn't have canvas.  From F12 you can switch it and see that you're site does work if it is in IE9 standards mode.

I think you want to put DOCTYPE html before everything else to avoid this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this in case it helps someone else (I found this page when I was googling)

Pages worked fine in Firefox

In IE9 pages were working locally, but not from server. ("getContext not supported etc. etc.") 
Had run out of ideas, but noticed that a trial of part of my page containing canvas did work.

Long story short:-
My pages were .htm  and so I thought "Is there an HTML5 standard ?" well I'm not sure if there is but when I changed all pages to .html the site behaved as intended in IE9 with all canvas elements working.

Bob